# Does $(x)\cdot \bigcap_{n\geq 0}(x^n)= \bigcap_{n\geq 0}(x^n)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring and $x\in R$. Is it true that both ideals $\bigcap_{n\geq 0}(x^n)$ and $(x)\cdot \bigcap_{n\geq 0}(x^n)$ are equal?

Clearly, the latter is included in the former, but does the other inclusion also hold in general? How can it be seen?

Comment: Artin-Rees Lemma seems relevant.